# How do these Zener diodes limit the maximum voltage seen by other circuit components?

Tags: zener, over-voltage-protection, diode-clamp

[image: Over Voltage Protection AN-1533 Texas Instruments]

This schematic is given in Texas Instrument's AN-1533 Application Note (Over Voltage Protection Circuit for Automotive Load Dump)

- On page 4, the author says that the D3 Zener prevents the cathode of D1 from exceeding its maximum voltage of 35V.
- Similarly, this same D3 Zener limits the Gate-to-Source voltage seen by Q2 to 20V.

How exactly is this limiting behaviour happening, and what would be the calculation that shows this at a Vin of 60V?

To me it looks like both D2 and D3 will breakdown and end up taking the full load current.

Comment: Load current flows through the load so D2 and D3 cannot take load current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D2 and D3 will limit the voltage, as they have limiting resistors, full load current does not go through them.

If there is 60V at Vin, and you assume the zeners to be ideal, D3 will limit to 6.8V and since current is provided only via resistor R3, there will be 60V-6.8V = 53.2V over R3, so only about 0.5mA will flow. So D3 protects the Vgs of Q2 and limits it to 6.8V.

Same thing with D2 really. D2 does nothing, unless voltage over R5 grows to 6.8V, and then it limits the voltage over R5 to 6.8V. This is the Vgs of Q1 it is protecting. And the current is again limited by R6, so only about 2.7mA will flow.